# Offer Bounty on Question

Tags: discussion, bounty

I've seen a nicely styled first question (Google Spreadsheet tag: [Google Sheets: "Split" delimited string, preserving blank entries](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/57614/29140)) and I would like to award a bounty.

Not to receive attention, but for the question/questioner itself. Has that been discussed or does it infringe with the privilege policy?

Comment: I'm still curious why people find questions interesting enough to _answer_ them but don't upvote the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not allowed under the current system.  See [Bounty-like facility for rewarding excellent questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135469/bounty-like-facility-for-rewarding-excellent-questions) and any of its duplicates for the rationale.

> The problem with offering bounties on questions is it doesn't encourage any behavior from other users. When users see a bounty available on a question, it encourages them to provide a detailed answer in an effort to be rewarded the bounty.

You could set a bounty on *behalf* of the user to help him/her get a good answer on the question.  Another (related) option would be to judiciously share a link to the question elsewhere to draw attention to it.

You could *technically* award a bounty on one of the user's answers, but consider whether this is really in the spirit of the system to do so.

Comment: Upvoting these questions would be a way to go, but I only have one upvote.......Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Jacob: When I've seen other excellent questions, I make sure that I publicize the question on Twitter/Facebook/Google+/etc. to at least get it more attention and (one is hopeful) more upvotes.

Comment: @Al E. That's some good advice, Al. Thanks.